# HTTP Post not connecting with angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to the stack and am building a test page to sort out my understanding before building my actual project. Right now, I'm just trying to take user input, save it to a database, and print it. The data should be saved in a basic Mongoose model, test. While all of the routes are open, instead of printing what the user entered it prints something in the following format:

```
{"_id":"55c3925b48b9dba0d896be40","__v":0}
```

I suspect it has something to do with the second line of this snippet from index.js:

```
router.post('/survey', function(req, res, next) {
    var test = new Test(req.body);

    test.save(function(err,test) {
        if(err) {
            return next(err);
        }

        res.json(test);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Relevent code:

All of index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

//set up routes
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Test = mongoose.model('Test');

router.get('/survey', function(req, res, next) {
    Test.find(function(err, tests) {
        if(err) {
          return next(err);
        }

        res.json(tests);
    });
});

router.post('/survey', function(req, res, next) {
    var test = new Test(req.body);

    test.save(function(err,test) {
        if(err) {
            return next(err);
        }

        res.json(test);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Tests.js (model):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var TestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    'name': String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Test', TestSchema);
```

Relevant bits of angular code:

```
routerApp.factory('tests', ['$http', function($http){
    var o = {
        tests: []
    };

    o.getAll = function() {
        return $http.get('/survey').success(function(data){
            console.log('get all sees data as:' + data);
            angular.copy(data, o.tests);
        });
    };

    o.create = function(test) {
        console.log('create sees test as' + test);
        return $http.post('/survey', test).success(function(data){
            o.tests.push(data);
            console.log('Data:' + data);
        });
    };

    return o;
}]);


routerApp.controller('FormCtrl', ['$scope', 'tests',
    function($scope, tests){
        $scope.test = tests.tests;

        $scope.addTest = function(){
            if(!$scope.text || $scope.text === '') { return; }
            tests.create({
                name: $scope.text
            });
            $scope.text = '';
        };
    }
]);
```

I suspect this is a matter of not understanding what kind of object req is, but I'm not entirely positive. How would I go about making this code save data in the format described in the mongoose model?

Comment: might be easier to separate concerns -- e.g., develop/test the server-side logic in an isolated fashion, using just `curl` (or a barebones web page) to POST your data to it. then focus on the angular/client-side code after. i do recognize that "_id" key-value pair in the JSON: it's the document id that gets autogenerated when a new document is inserted into MongoDB, so something is apparently being inserted, at least

Comment: It's definitely a POST error. I can go into the mongo shell and documents are definitely being created. Somewhere the information from $scope does not make its way to $save; I'm just not quite sure where.

Comment: @lispHK01, Just used curl to add a document, it did not save any of the attributes I used, but instead saved in the format {id, v}--so it is in the POST method itself.

Comment: and if I explicitly define test (i.e. var test = new Test ({"name":"test"});) it does save the attribute, so it it the req.body statement that is causing the issue.

Comment: hmm, only thing i can think of is maybe value of `req.body` needs to be parsed -- i.e., ensure that the raw body, which probably looks like  "name=foo",  is converted a bona fide JavaScript object like `{name: 'foo'}` by the time it gets passed into the `Test` constructor.

Comment: just saw your last comment -- ok ya sounds like that's probably it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you call [`.toObject()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) on the document object (`res.json(test.toObject())`), you should get a plain object back containing the data in that document.

Comment: It doesn't seem to run when I do that...any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to `console.log(req.body)`. If it's empty, then try adding `app.use(bodyParser.json())` somewhere before your routes are defined (and be sure to install it with npm and `require` it first).

When you POST some sort of JSON, it isn't available in `req.body` by default. You need `bodyParser` to parse the incoming data and make it available in `req.body`. See https://medium.com/@adamzerner/how-bodyparser-works-247897a93b90 for more info.